# List of unique product by reflection?

Tags: java, arrays, list, reflection

I looking for solution how to make List (or something) with unique Product. The reason i want to do it is total price of Product. Each sets can contains same Product.

Here's my classes.

```
public class Product {

  public String name; // unique name
  public double price;
  public double qty;

}
```

&

```
public class Sets {
  public Product item1;
  public Product item2;
  ...
  public Product item7;
  public static listsProduct<Product> = new Arraylists<Product>();
}
```

I'm trying to make a Lists but i don't know how to add a unique product. To add Product i use reflection.

My method:

```
 public void getProducts() throws NoSuchMethodException, Exception {
     Sets object = this;
     Class clazz = object.getClass();
     Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
     Method m1 = Product.class.getMethod("getname", null);
     for (Field field : fields) {
       if(field.get(object)!=null) {
         System.out.println(field.getName()+" = " + m1.invoke(field.get(object),null));
         Product e=(Product) field.get(object);
         if (listsProduct==null ) listsProduct.add((Produkt) field.get(object));
         if (!(listsProduct.contains(field.get(object)))) listsProduct.add(e);

        }
     }
```

It's adding a Product correctly but how make UNIQUE lists?

Thanks in advance for any help !

**EDIT :** 
So... What do u want achieve?
eg.

sets :

1) butter, milk, peanut

2) goodie, butter, xxx

3) milk, peanut, xxx

**result:**
List of unique product

1. butter
2. milk
3. peanut
4. xxx
5. goodie

if product exist on lists **sum price**

Comment: What does `public static listsProduct<Product> = new Arraylists<Product>();` mean? Does it mean `public static List<Product> listsProduct = new Arraylists<Product>();`?

Comment: @BenjyKessler yes, sry i was modifying code in editor

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Do you got a set of products, of which some of them can be the same product (as in, the same name), and if they are you want to merge them to one product with the sum of their qtys?

Comment: The method also deserves a better formatting and if you are rewriting it, maybe do it in a way, that it is at least compilable.

Comment: I don't understand what you want or what you're asking. What does *"how make UNIQUE lists?"* mean?

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection? If you overwrite hashCode/equals on Product to do the right thing you can just all all products to any Set<Product> and it will give you the uniques automatically.

Comment: @m0skit0 i got X sets. Every set can contain same products. I'd like to make lists of unique product from x sets eg. 1set){ milk, butter, cheese }2set){peanut, bread, xxx} 3set){butter, peanut, cheese} lists: {milk,butter,cheese,bread,xxx}

Comment: Edit your question and put that example there. And what should happen if you add a new repeated element to the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the [*Reflection API*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) for things like this!

One way to get a list of unique products would be to use [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) with the **Product name** as **key** and the **Product::merge** method from this example as the **remapping function**.

---

Given a class *Product*...

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    double price;
    int qty;

    public Product(String name, double price, int qty) {
        this.name = name; this.price = price; this.qty = qty;
    }

    public Product merge(Product p) {
        price += p.price;
        qty += p.qty;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s x %d (%.2f)", name, qty, price);
    }
}
```

And a *List* of *Sets* of *Products*:

```
List<Set<Product>> sets = asList(
    new HashSet<>(asList(new Product("cheese", 5, 1), new Product("milk", 3, 3))),
    new HashSet<>(asList(new Product("peanut", 1, 1), new Product("bread", 2, 1))),
    new HashSet<>(asList(new Product("cheese", 5, 1), new Product("peanut", 1, 1)))
);
```

A *Collection* of unique *Products* can be created like this:

```
private static Collection<Product> listProducts(List<Set<Product>> sets) {
    Map<String, Product> uniques = new HashMap<>();
    for(Set<Product> set : sets)
        for(Product p : set)
            uniques.merge(p.name, p, (a, b) -> a.merge(b));
    return uniques.values();
}
```

---

Full working example:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UniqProd {
    public static class Product {
        String name;
        double price;
        int qty;

        public Product(String name, double price, int qty) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.qty = qty;
        }

        public Product merge(Product p) {
            price += p.price;
            qty += p.qty;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s x %d (%.2f)", name, qty, price);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Set<Product>> sets = asList(
            new HashSet<>(asList(new Product("cheese", 5, 1), new Product("milk", 3, 3))),
            new HashSet<>(asList(new Product("peanut", 1, 1), new Product("bread", 2, 1))),
            new HashSet<>(asList(new Product("cheese", 5, 1), new Product("peanut", 1, 1)))
        );

        listProducts(sets).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Collection<Product> listProducts(List<Set<Product>> sets) {
        Map<String, Product> uniques = new HashMap<>();
        for (Set<Product> set : sets)
            for (Product p : set)
                uniques.merge(p.name, p, (a, b) -> a.merge(b));
        return uniques.values();
    }
}
```

---

If you, for some reason, must/want to use your Sets class instead of a java.util.Set, construct a List of the products in your Sets instance before iterating it:

```
private static Collection<Product> listProducts(List<Sets> sets) {
    Map<String, Product> uniques = new HashMap<>();
    for (Sets set : sets)
        for (Product p : asList(set.item1, set.item2, set.item3))
            uniques.merge(p.name, p, (a, b) -> a.merge(b));
    return uniques.values();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't get why you want to use reflection , I am giving below answer to solve your problem of `how to store unique products ?`

If you want to add unique products . you must define that what makes the product Unique? Lets assume that product name will help you identifying whether they are not-equal/unique.

To define it let's write equals &hashcode method in product class

```
public class Product {

  public String name; // unique name
  public double price;
  public double qty;

  public boolean equals(Object obj){
   if (obj ==null || ! obj instanceOf Prpduct) return false;
   else return ((Product) obj).name.equals(name);// also write a null check conditions for name field.
 }
 public interest hashCode(){ 
return name.hashCode();
 }

}
```

Now change your data structure from List to Set 
which will store only distinct Products , like below 
`

```
public class Sets {
  public Product item1;
  public Product item2;
  ...
  public Product item7;
  public static Set<Product> productSet= new HashSet<Product>();
}
```

`
With this whenever you will add productSet only unique would get stored.